# How to use dotnet watch with release configuration and arguments passed to the application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-cli, dotnet-watch

Let's use the following code for simulating the problem.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var arg in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use `dotnet watch -c release -- hello world` but the output is:

```
-c
release
hello
world
```

The expected output:

```
hello
world
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dotnet watch` does not have `-c|--configuration` switch/option ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-watch#options)), `dotnet run` has ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run#options)).

`dotnet watch` allows to specify the command to be watched (`dotnet watch run`) though passing `-c` has not worked for me (i.e. `dotnet watch run -c release -- hello world`) but passing the MSBuild property directly with `--property:Configuration=RELEASE` did:

```
dotnet watch run --property:Configuration=RELEASE -- hello world
```

Sample program used for tests:

```
#if DEBUG
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World DEBUG!");
#else
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World NOT_DEBUG!");
#endif
foreach (var arg in args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arg);
}
```

Comment: For others, note that all are case insensitive. `--property:Configuration=RELEASE` can be also written as `--property:configuration=release`.